# Can i emulate my cloud function triggered by firebase analytics event in Firebase Emulate Suite?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics, firebase-tools

When app was uninstalled, i want to collect user information (such as 'user_id') by listen 'app_remove' event. The codes of cloud function are as follows.

```
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const functions = require('firebase-functions/v1');

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

exports.logAppRemove = functions.analytics.event("app_remove").onLog((event) => {
    const user = event.user;
    const uid = user.userId;
    console.log("uid = " + uid);
    console.log("event : " + JSON.stringify(event));
    return null;
});
```

When i use firebase local emulator suite to emulate the function, it show logs as follows. Did I use something incorrectly or misunderstand it?

```
Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
Watching "/../../../../../functions" for Cloud Functions...
functions: Using node@20 from host.
Serving at port 8855
Loaded functions definitions from source: logAppRemove.
function ignored because the analytics emulator does not exist or is not running.
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150
```

Comment: Using the shell, you mock data and perform function calls to simulate interaction with products that the Local Emulator Suite does not currently support: Analytics, Remote Config, and Crashlytics. [What other tools for testing Cloud Functions exist?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions)